# i was learning about jquery animate function,and came across the following code,didnt figure out what $extend() actually does

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

```
(function animation() {
   var options = {
      duration: 800,
      easing: 'linear'
   };

   $('.square-big')
      .find('.square-small')
      .animate({
            left: 280,
            top: 280
         },
         options
      )
      .animate({
            left: 0,
         },
         options
      )
      .animate({
            left: 280,
            top: 0,
         },
         options
      )
      .animate({
            left: 0,
         },
         $.extend(true, {}, options, {
            complete: function() {
               animation();
            }
         })
      );
})();
```

i went through the jquery documentation and it says extend merges content of two or more object into the first object.adding true makes the extend recurssive.but i just could not figure out what is being megred where in the above case.i am doomed here.(i am just starting out on jquery)

Comment: From where comes from this code?

Answer (score 0):

`$.extend()` merges objects together, as you say. In your case, you are merging `options` and an object containing your `complete` function into an empty object, leaving the original objects as they were before the `$.extend()`.

Splitting this into steps:

1. The object defined in the second parameter is our starting point

   ```
   {}
   ```
2. The next object, `options`, is then merged into the first one, which gives us this:

   ```
   {
       duration: 800,
       easing: 'linear'
   }
   ```
3. The next object, which you have defined to contain the `complete` function is then merged in to the object:

   ```
   {
       duration: 800,
       easing: 'linear',
       complete: function() {
          animation();
       }
   }
   ```
4. The result is then returned from `$.extend()` and passed in to the final animation.